# Find the indexes of dependent columns

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a fairly large singular square matrix, of size 37 and rank 35.

Is there a way to get a vector with the (groups of) indexes of the columns in the original matrix that are linearly dependent?

RowReduce et al won't help me, because they perform an arbitrary number of row swaps.

Comment: But it doesn't perform column swap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to start with empty matrix. Add the first column. Then loop, each time adding the next column, and checking if the rank of this matrix has increased from before, if so, keep it, else skip over to the next column. Keep doing this until you reach the last column in the original matrix, or have collected m columns, where m is the rank of the original matrix. (no need to keep trying if found m columns).

### function

```
indepCols[mat_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Module[{nRows, nCols, m, idx, 
    i, vecs, candidate},

  {nRows, nCols} = Dimensions[mat];
  m = MatrixRank[mat];
  idx = Table[1, {m}]; (*arrary to collect the index of columns*)
  vecs = {mat[[All, 1]]}; (*first column is always in*)
  Do[
   candidate = Join[vecs, {mat[[All, i]]}];
   If[MatrixRank[candidate] > Length[vecs],(*did the rank increase?*)
    idx[[Length[vecs] + 1]] = i;
    vecs = candidate;
    If[Length[vecs] == m, Break[]](*bail out if got the rank*)
    ],
   {i, 2, nCols}
   ];

  {idx, vecs}
  ]
```

To use the above function:

### First example

```
(mat = {{1, 0, -2, 1, 0}, {0, -1, -3, 1, 3}, {-2, -1, 1, -1, 3}, 
     {-2, -1, 1, -1, 3}, {0, 3, 9, 0, -12}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above has rank 3. So there will be 3 L.I. columns

```
 {idx, out} = indepCols[mat];
 Transpose[out] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
idx
(*{1, 2, 4}*)
```

Verified using "AdjacencyLists" thanks to Michael E2 above.

```
sa = Transpose@Unitize@SparseArray@RowReduce[mat];
row2col = Rule @@@ Reverse /@ First /@ GatherBy[sa["NonzeroPositions"], First];
Thread[Range[First@Dimensions@sa] -> (sa["AdjacencyLists"] /. row2col)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### second example

Using example given by Michael E2, which is much larger

```
SeedRandom[1];
mat = RandomSample[#~Join~Accumulate@RandomSample[#, 2] &@
    RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {35, 37}]];
{idx, out} = indepCols[mat];
idx
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verified:

```
sa = Transpose@Unitize@SparseArray@RowReduce[mat];
row2col = Rule @@@ Reverse /@ First /@ GatherBy[sa["NonzeroPositions"], First];
Thread[Range[First@Dimensions@sa] -> (sa["AdjacencyLists"] /. row2col)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above gives the index of the L.I. columns. To find the index of the L.D. columns,
simply take the complement:

```
Complement[Range[1, Length[mat]], idx]
(*{36, 37}*)
```

Comment: Also very sweet. Thanks to the both of you. +1 for now until I can get my hands on my matrix again.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution, mostly because I understand it, given my relatively short knowledge of Mathematica advanced programming.

Answer (score 6):

If `RowReduce` won't help, then perhaps I don't know what you're looking for.  Here's my understanding of the question in which I use `RowReduce` to get the answer.

**Example**

A random matrix:

```
SeedRandom[1];
mat = RandomSample[#~Join~Accumulate@RandomSample[#, 2] &@
    RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {35, 37}]];
MatrixRank[mat]
(*  35  *)
```

We can use the `SparseArray` property `"AdjacencyLists"` to find for each column, which columns it depends on.  I'm not sure what form the final result should be in.  The output below indicates for each column, which columns it is a linear of.  An entry of the form `i -> {i}` indicates an independent vector.  The entry `21 -> {3, 8}` indicates that column 21 is a linear combinations of columns 3 and 8.  The leading 1 in each nonzero row of the reduced matrix indicates the column with which the columns with nonzero entries in the row have a relationship.  The set of rules `row2col` basically indicates for each row, the column in which the leading 1 is located.

```
sa = Transpose @ Unitize @ SparseArray @ RowReduce[mat2];
row2col = 
  Rule @@@ Reverse /@ First /@ GatherBy[sa["NonzeroPositions"], First];
Thread[Range[First @ Dimensions @ sa] -> (sa["AdjacencyLists"] /. row2col)]
(*
{1 -> {1}, 2 -> {2}, 3 -> {3}, 4 -> {4}, 5 -> {5}, 6 -> {6}, 7 -> {7},
 8 -> {8}, 9 -> {9}, 10 -> {10}, 11 -> {11}, 12 -> {12}, 13 -> {13}, 
 14 -> {14}, 15 -> {15}, 16 -> {16}, 17 -> {17}, 18 -> {18}, 
 19 -> {19}, 20 -> {20},
 21 -> {3, 8},
 22 -> {22}, 23 -> {23}, 24 -> {24},
 25 -> {3},
 26 -> {26}, 27 -> {27}, 28 -> {28}, 
 29 -> {29}, 30 -> {30}, 31 -> {31}, 32 -> {32}, 33 -> {33}, 
 34 -> {34}, 35 -> {35}, 36 -> {36}, 37 -> {37}}
*)
```

Comment: nice use of "AdjacencyLists", I had no idea such a thing exist.

Comment: @Nasser [Mr.Wizard's answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A121+AdjacencyLists) make a nice course of study.

Comment: @MichaelE2, are there more strings like "AdjacencyLists" and "NonzeroPositions", and if so, where can I read about them? I could not even find these two in the help page for SparseArray or the Tutorials "Sparse Arrays: Manipulating Lists/Linear Algebra".

Comment: This is good stuff. I'll test it on my matrix tomorrow, but it looks like exactly what I was looking for. +1 for now.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Many data structures like `SparseArray` take an argument `"Properties"` and return a list of possible inputs. Try `sa["Properties"]`.  I cannot always find out how to use them or even if they're implemented.  Searching for the string + data structure on this site sometimes yields results.  Or you can ask question here.  Often they're not documented.